# Matlab , solve() and drawing ball trajectory

Tags: matlab

I want to draw the trajectory of a flying ball and find where it will fall.
I have g = 9,81, start height h = 1,5m, start speed v = 4 m/s and angle a = 45

A ball is thrown at angle 45 , from initial height 1,5m ,with speed 4 m/s.

And I have these formulas:

y = h + v*t*sin(a)- (g*t^2)/2
x = v*t*cos(a)

First , I want to find a place where the ball will fall.

```
syms t
h0 = 1.5;
a = 45;
g = 9.81;
v = 4;
p = solve(h0 + v*t*sind(a)-(1/2)*g*t^2 == 0,t);
```

So, I'm trying to find ball's "flying time", to then find where ball will fall Xmax = v*p*cos(a). But this returns some weird things.

What I'm doing wrong here?

And when I'm trying to draw the trajectory of a flying ball with matlabFunction I'm getting strange trajectories.

```
h = h0 + v*t*sind(a)-(1/2)*g*t^2;
x = v*cosd(a)*t;
hf = matlabFunction(h);
xf = matlabFunction(x);
fplot(hf,xf)
```

What should I change to draw real ball trajectory ?

Sorry for stupid question, I'm working with matlab for only one hour so I don't really know what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the quadratic equation symbolically returns two solutions in symbolic form. You probably want to evaluate them and use the one that's larger (not the one in the "past", with negative time):

```
T = max(eval(p));
```

To plot the trajectory, I would use the  `plot` command with numerical data fed into it. That is, create an array of t-values with `linspace`, evaluate x and h at these values, and feed these coordinates into `plot`:

```
t = linspace(0,T);
h = h0 + v*t*sind(a)-(1/2)*g*t.^2;
x = v*cosd(a)*t;
plot(x,h)
```

[image: plot]